# Why the program of linked lists in C++ only displays the maximum number and ignores minimum number?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I have written this code using C++ to display the max and min number of the linked list, when I run the code I can get the maximum number but I cannot get the minimum number and its value always zero:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int a;
    Node* next; 
};

Node* createNode(int num) {
    Node* n = new Node();
    n->a = num;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}

void addValue(int a, Node** h) {

    Node* y = createNode(a), * p = *h;
    if (*h == NULL)
        *h = y;
    else {
        while (p->next != NULL) 
            p = p->next;    
        p->next = y;
    }
}

void display(Node* x) {
    while (x != NULL) {
        cout << x->a << " ";
        x = x->next;
    }
}

double sumNodes(Node** h) {
    double sum = 0;
    Node* x = *h;

    while (x != NULL) {
        sum += x->a;
        x = x->next;
    }
    return sum;
}

void minmax(Node* numH1, Node* numH2) {
    double max = 0, min = 0;

    while (numH1 != NULL) {
        if (max < numH1->a)
            max = numH1->a;
        numH1 = numH1->next;
    }
    cout << "max: " << max << endl;

    while (numH2 != NULL) {

    if (min > numH2->a)
        min = numH2->a;
    numH2 = numH2->next;
    }
    cout << "min: " << min;

}

int main() {
    int num = 0;  char choice;
    Node* head1 = NULL;
    Node* head2 = NULL;
    do {
        cout << "Enter a number : ";
        cin >> num;
        addValue(num, &head1);
        cout << "Enter [Y] to add another number : ";
        cin >> choice;
    } while (choice == 'Y');

    cout << endl;
     minmax(head1, head2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have to use one function to display both maximum and minimum numbers from the linked lsit, not sure what went wrong exactly

Comment: `double max = 0, min = 0;` -- Ideally, the max should start out at the lowest number, and the `min` should start out at the highest possible number.  The `min` should not start at 0.  You also don't need to have two loops -- just one loop is all that's required.  I also don't see where `head2` gets any data added to it.

Comment: So to what should I assign `min = numH->no`

Comment: notice that it will fail if you enter negative numbers too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set min to a high value, if you set it to 0 then this is never true

```
if (min > numH2->a)
```

so do

```
 #include <limits>
 ....
 double max = 0, min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
```

or if you arent allowed to use limits (omg wtf)

```
 double max = 0, min = 999999999;
```

actually here is DBL_MAX for you (which is what numeric_limits would give you)

```
 double max = 0, min = 1.79769e+308;
```

also becuase this is a double (signed) max should be set to smallest possible

```
 double max = 2.22507e-308; // DBL_MIN
 double min = 1.79769e+308; // DBL_MAX
```

Comment: thanks but I'm not allowed to include <limits>

Comment: Let me be the first one to say, "That's hilarious!" I can see cases for restricting use of vector, string, or other container and helper header for particular assignments where you're required to implement the functionality of the forbidden header, but limits is just a huge stack of useful numbers. If you can't use limits and get the actual limitations of the system, put in a gawdawful big number like 10 to the power of 100 and hope the tester never exceeds it.

Comment: @user4581301 I assume that they have a list of 'allowed includes' and limits is not on it, I cant imagine it being explicitly banned

Comment: Another approach would be to set `max` and `min` to the value of the first item in the list; then you don't have to worry about irrelevant constants potentially affecting the computation.  (You do need to make sure the list isn't empty before you try this, though!)

Comment: Good point. Lot of headers in C++, so a whitelist makes sense. Wonder if c's float.h is available.